# python cut row in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
0                    г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Карпинского,
1                   г. Челябинск, проспект Комсомольский,
2                         г. Екатеринбург, ул. Щербакова,
3             г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Латышских Стрелков,
4       г. Москва, вн.тер.г. муниципальный округ Измай...
```

I want all between 'г.' and ',' like

```
0                   Санкт-Петербург
1                   Челябинск
2                   Екатеринбург
3                   Санкт-Петербург
4                   Москва
```

I have code data['col'] = data['address'].str.extract('(г.*,)') but it doesn't give me desired result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with:

```
data['col'] = data['address'].str.extract(r'г. *([^,]+),', expand=False)
```

output:

```
                                             address              col
0               г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Карпинского,  Санкт-Петербург
1              г. Челябинск, проспект Комсомольский,        Челябинск
2                    г. Екатеринбург, ул. Щербакова,     Екатеринбург
3        г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Латышских Стрелков,  Санкт-Петербург
4  г. Москва, вн.тер.г. муниципальный округ Измай...           Москва
```

Comment: I would rename df to data just to remain consistent with the question

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `split()` for this case given the pattern:

```
data['col'] = [x.split()[1][:-1] for x in data['address']]
```

Returning:

```
                                col
0                   Санкт-Петербург
1                         Челябинск
2                      Екатеринбург
3                   Санкт-Петербург
4                           Москва
```

Comment: Default for split is space. This wouldn't work since there is comma after city name ' г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Карпинского'

Comment: This matches exactly what OP requires...?

Comment: It procudes the desired output. But I think there could be a more informative way through regex